# Regular expression if a word contains some character then must not contain another character pattern

Tags: regex

I want to check a given string using **regular expression** if any of words contains for example `q-w` characters then must not contain `ı-ş` characters.

```
given string = > abc qşl def , not matches
given string = > abc qsl def , matches
```

Best Regards,
HH

Comment: Must the prohibited characters appear after the required characters, or can either appear in any order?

Comment: The range `ı-ş` is pretty large

Comment: It's actually just 45 characters. Don't confuse `ı` (dotless i) with `l` or even `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^ı-ş]*[q-w][^ı-ş]*$|^[^q-w]*$
```

[Here is a demonstration](http://www.rubular.com/r/DhdyixbS1e).
Is that what you mean?